# AWS API gateway cannot connect to ECS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I try to setup and deploy a test web server using ECR and ECS, then create the API gateway to talk to the container running on the image.
But I cannot get the API to talk with the ECS instance. Everytime I call to the API the response is always 404

The image i use is a simple asp.net web server returning helloworld command on GET on port 80.
The cloud formation I use is as follow, the image I use has been ommited out since it is my private ECR image but it just a basic web server returning hello world text

```
# Copyright Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Description: Demo of an AWS Fargate cluster hosting APIs exposed through API Gateway.

Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
    Default: ecsapi-demo
    Description: "A friendly environment name that will be used for namespacing all cluster resources. Example: staging, qa, or production"
  PrivateDNSNamespaceName:
    Type: String
    Default: service
    Description: "The private DNS name that identifies the name that you want to use to locate your resources"
 
  AutoScalingTargetValueMicroservices:
    Type: Number
    Default: 50
    Description: "Target CPU utilizatio (%) for ECS services auto scaling"
  

Metadata: 
  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface: 
    ParameterGroups: 
      - 
        Label: 
          default: "Generic"
        Parameters: 
          - EnvironmentName
          - PrivateDNSNamespaceName
      - 
        Label: 
          default: "Microservices Service"
        Parameters: 
          - AutoScalingTargetValueMicroservices

Mappings:
  SubnetConfig:
    VPC:
      CIDR: '10.0.0.0/16'
    PublicOne:
      CIDR: '10.0.0.0/24'
    PrivateOne:
      CIDR: '10.0.100.0/24'

Resources:

  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap ['SubnetConfig', 'VPC', 'CIDR']

  PublicSubnetOne:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select
        - 0
        - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap ['SubnetConfig', 'PublicOne', 'CIDR']
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true

  PrivateSubnetOne:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select
        - 0
        - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap ['SubnetConfig', 'PrivateOne', 'CIDR']

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway

  GatewayAttachement:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref 'InternetGateway'

  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'

  PublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: GatewayAttachement
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref 'PublicRouteTable'
      DestinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0'
      GatewayId: !Ref 'InternetGateway'

  PublicSubnetOneRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetOne
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable


  NatGatewayOneAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: GatewayAttachement
    Properties:
        Domain: vpc
  
  NatGatewayOne:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGatewayOneAttachment.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetOne
  
  PrivateRouteTableOne:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
  PrivateRouteOne:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTableOne
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGatewayOne
  PrivateRouteTableOneAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTableOne
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnetOne

  ECSCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterSettings:
      - Name: containerInsights
        Value: enabled

  ContainerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Access to the Fargate containers
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'

  ContainerSecurityGroupSelfIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref ContainerSecurityGroup
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ContainerSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 80
      ToPort: 80

  AutoScalingRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceAutoscaleRole'

  ECSRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ecs.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: ecs-service
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'ec2:AttachNetworkInterface'
              - 'ec2:CreateNetworkInterface'
              - 'ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission'
              - 'ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface'
              - 'ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfacePermission'
              - 'ec2:Describe*'
              - 'ec2:DetachNetworkInterface'

              - 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer'
              - 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets'
              - 'elasticloadbalancing:Describe*'
              - 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer'
              - 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets'
            Resource: '*'

  ECSTaskExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                # Allow the ECS Tasks to download images from ECR
                - 'ecr:GetAuthorizationToken'
                - 'ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability'
                - 'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer'
                - 'ecr:BatchGetImage'

                # Allow the ECS tasks to upload logs to CloudWatch
                - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
              Resource: '*'

  PrivateDNSNamespace:
    Type: 'AWS::ServiceDiscovery::PrivateDnsNamespace'
    Properties:
      Vpc: !Ref VPC
      Name: !Ref PrivateDNSNamespaceName

  ServiceDiscoveryMicroservices:
    Type: 'AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Service'
    Properties:
      DnsConfig:
        DnsRecords:
          - Type: SRV
            TTL: 60
        NamespaceId: !Ref PrivateDNSNamespace
      HealthCheckCustomConfig:
        FailureThreshold: 1
      Name: 'services.microservice'

  TaskRoleMicroservices:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: dynamodb-table-access
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - dynamodb:BatchGet*
            - dynamodb:DescribeStream
            - dynamodb:DescribeTable
            - dynamodb:Get*
            - dynamodb:Query
            - dynamodb:Scan
            - dynamodb:BatchWrite*
            - dynamodb:CreateTable
            - dynamodb:Delete*
            - dynamodb:Update*
            - dynamodb:PutItem
            Resource: !GetAtt DynamoDBTableMicroservices.Arn

  TaskDefinitionMicroservices:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'
    Properties:
      TaskRoleArn: !GetAtt TaskRoleMicroservices.Arn
      ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt ECSTaskExecutionRole.Arn
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      ContainerDefinitions:
          - Name: 'Microservices'
            Image: '' # ommited
            Essential: true
            PortMappings:
              - ContainerPort: 80
                Protocol: tcp
            LogConfiguration:
              LogDriver: awslogs
              Options:
                awslogs-create-group: true
                awslogs-group: /ecs/microservice
                awslogs-region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs-microservice
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      Memory: '512'
      Cpu: '256'

  Microservices: 
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn:
      - PrivateRouteOne
    Properties: 
      Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinitionMicroservices
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      DesiredCount: 1
      ServiceRegistries:
        - RegistryArn: !GetAtt ServiceDiscoveryMicroservices.Arn
          Port: 80
      NetworkConfiguration:
          AwsvpcConfiguration:
            AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
            Subnets:
              - !Ref PrivateSubnetOne
            SecurityGroups:
              - !Ref ContainerSecurityGroup


  AutoScalingTargetMicroservices:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
    Properties:
      MinCapacity: 1
      MaxCapacity: 1
      ResourceId: !Join ['/', [service, !Ref ECSCluster, !GetAtt Microservices.Name]]
      ScalableDimension: ecs:service:DesiredCount
      ServiceNamespace: ecs
      RoleARN: !GetAtt AutoScalingRole.Arn

  AutoScalingPolicyMicroservices:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: !Join ['', [!GetAtt Microservices.Name, '-AutoScalingPolicy']]
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      ScalingTargetId: !Ref AutoScalingTargetMicroservices
      TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization
        TargetValue: !Ref AutoScalingTargetValueMicroservices

  HttpApiVPCLink:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::VpcLink
    Properties: 
      Name: !Ref EnvironmentName
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - !Ref ContainerSecurityGroup
      SubnetIds: 
        - !Ref PrivateSubnetOne

  HttpApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
    Properties:
      Body:
        openapi: "3.0.1"
        info:
          title: !Ref EnvironmentName
        paths:
          /microservice/{proxy+}:
            x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
              responses:
                default:
                  description: "Default response for GET /microservice/"
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                payloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
                connectionId: !Ref HttpApiVPCLink
                type: "http_proxy"
                httpMethod: "ANY"
                uri: !GetAtt ServiceDiscoveryMicroservices.Arn
                connectionType: "VPC_LINK"
  HttpApiStage:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage'
    Properties:
      StageName: '$default'
      ApiId: !Ref 'HttpApi'
      AutoDeploy: true

Outputs:
  APIInvokeURL:
    Description: Invoke URL for the HTTP API
    Value: !Sub 'https://${HttpApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com'
  APIInvokeURLMicroservices:
    Description: Invoke URL for the HTTP API for the service Foodstore Foods
    Value: !Sub 'https://${HttpApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/microservice/'
  APIId:
    Description: The ID of the HTTP API
    Value: !Ref 'HttpApi'
  ECSClusterName:
    Description: The name of the ECS cluster
    Value: !Ref 'ECSCluster'
  VpcId:
    Description: The ID of the VPC that this stack is deployed in
    Value: !Ref 'VPC'
  ContainerSecurityGroup:
    Description: A security group used to allow Fargate containers to receive traffic
    Value: !Ref 'ContainerSecurityGroup'
  PrivateDNSNamespace:
    Description: The ID of the private DNS namespace.
    Value: !Ref 'PrivateDNSNamespace'
```

What i have tried:

- Check if the container is fine: yes, pulling the image to local and run it work fine. the container is running on fargate and the log output fine
- Check if the cloud map valid: i have checked the IP of the mapping and it map correctly to the private ip of the container

I am quite new to the entire AWS stack and hope someone could help me

Comment: Have you tried setting this up without CloudFormation first, to get some experience with it in the console? Since you're new to AWS, this might help you identify something in the template that's not configured correctly.